# How to Covert below Dataframe? which Join to use to clean this Datafram

Tags: python, pandas

I Have this Dataframe -

**Name**    **Sum** **District**    **State**
A      10   Agra    UP
A   20  Agra    UP
B   20  Patna   Bihar
B   10  Patna   Bihar
B   20  Patna   Bihar
C   50  Kanpur  UP
D   10  New Delhi   Delhi
A   10  Agra    UP
B   20  Patna   Bihar
C   10  Kanpur  UP

and I want to convert into a data frame with conditions
Col1- contains each name only once
Col2- Total of all the sum with respect to col1
col3- First occurrence of the district of the name from col1
col4- First occurrence of the State of the name from col1

**Name**    **Sum** **District**    **State**
A   40  Agra    UP
B   70  Patna   Bihar
C   60  Kanpur  UP
D   10  New Delhi   Delhi

---

**==What I have tried till now==**
 I used Groupby name that gives me the name and the total sum but not District and State

Comment: Maybe: `df.groupby(['Name', 'District', 'State']).sum().reset_index()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you tried `df.groupby('Name').sum()`, which calculates *sum* (so far OK),
but only for **numeric** columns.

To process also columns of other types, you should use aggregation,
where you specify both column names and functions to apply to them.

Start from defining a lambda function getting the first element from a Series:

```
frst = lambda x: x.iloc[0]
```

Then call *groupby* with aggregation:

- *sum* function applied to *Sum* column,
- *frst* (the above function) to 2 other columns.

The code to do it can be:

```
df.groupby('Name').agg({'Sum': sum, 'District': frst, 'State': frst})
```